# How to verify the HMAC in this Python cryptography code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, base64, hmac

I am studying cryptography in Python and here is a Python 3 practice problem which is supposed to return "yes" as the input and output should match. Please tell me the right way of the second person (Hardy) to verify the message while using HMAC? I tried compare_digest() and base64decode but it doesn't work.

**Question-**
Laurel and Hardy are exchanging messages. However, Hardy is unsure about whether he is getting messages from Laurel. The following code is a simulation of HMAC even though the message and the key are the same, the HMAC is different. Modify the code so that Hardy knows with a guarantee that he has received the message from Laurel.

**Code-**

```
import hashlib
import base64

# Laurel and Hardy share a secret key
key = "apple".encode()


# Laurel sends Hardy a message---->
def laurel_to_hardy():
    message = input()
    msg = message.encode()
    #Laurel sends...
    #Laurel also sends hmac...
    
    sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
    sha256.update(msg)
    sha256.update(key)
    hmac = sha256.digest()
    
    return msg, hmac

#Verification by Hardy---------->
def hardy_verification(msg, hmac):
    #Hardy receives the message...
    #Hardy starts verification...
    
    # 000 PLEASE SUGGEST HERE#

    sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
    sha256.update(key)
    sha256.update(msg)
    hmac_hardy = sha256.digest()
    

    #Hardy receives
    if hmac_hardy == hmac:
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "no"
# Print ------>
    
msg_rec, hmac_rec = laurel_to_hardy()
print(hardy_verification(msg_rec, hmac_rec))
```

Thank you!

Comment: not sure your code does what you were thinking it would do, to make it work just swap sha256.update(key) sha256.update(msg) in sha256.update(msg) sha256.update(key) in def hardy_verification(msg, hmac): to have it printing 'yes'

Comment: That's not an hmac. But anyway you reversed the order of the key and the message in your verification code, as the previous comment noted.

Answer (score -1):

not an expert here but have a look at what this code outputs:

```
import hashlib

import copy

a = 'ABC'

a = a.encode()

h1 = hashlib.sha256(a)

b = copy.copy(a)

h2 = hashlib.sha256(b)

print(h1)

print(h2)

print(h1.digest())

print(h2.digest())


print(h1 == h2)

print(h1.digest() == h2.digest())



a = 'DDD'

c ='ooo'

a = a.encode()

c = c.encode()

h1 = hashlib.sha256(a)

h1.update(c)

b = copy.copy(a)

d = copy.copy(c)


h2 = hashlib.sha256(b)

h2.update(d)

print(h1)

print(h2)

print(h1.digest())

print(h2.digest())


print(h1 == h2)

print(h1.digest() == h2.digest())
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: Helped me ho understand the non-sense (to me ) above. Since you are reading here: do you have a two liner about what HMAC is ? New to cryptography but thought was an encryption method not a part of a secure two way encrypted comunnication as in Keyed-Hashing for Message Authentication lib/hmac.py

Comment: A message authentication code or [*MAC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) has a long formal definition but basically it's like a hash function that includes a secret key. What OP has shown is a home-grown MAC. An [*HMAC*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2104) is a very specific way of constructing a MAC from a hash function. The point of these MACs is to detect when data has been modified.

Comment: In shorter term uses the same hashlib function of the above code